# bash script echo and expect input password for git pull ssh url doesn't work

Tags: bash, git, expect

Currently i'm writing a bash script to cd into a folder and run git pull with the password prompt

Notes: my git server is private so i'm using the following git remote url ssh://username@ip-address/path-to-git-folder so i can't use https with password within the url

I'm trying the following bash script

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /path-to-repo/repo-folder
echo "mygitpassword" | sudo -S git pull
```

which doesn't work, i checked and it doesn't pull the changes

i also tried to used `expect` command prompt like the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /path-to-repo/repo-folder
/usr/bin/expect <<EOF
spawn git pull
expect -re "^.*password.*$"
send -- "mygitpassword\r"
EOF
echo "Done"
```

from the debug i can see that the regex matched and it's sending the "mygitpassword" (i can't copy paste the debug because i'm using a streaming machine)

summary of the expect debug output:

```
...
expect: does 'username@ip password: '(spawn_id exp6) match regular expression "^.*password.*$"? Gate "*password*? gate=yes re=yes
expect: set expect_out(0, string) "username@ip's password: "
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp6"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) "username@ip's password: "
send: sending "mygitpassword\r" to { exp6 }
Done
```

both methods showing it running till the echo "Done" but none are actually inputing the password

Right now i'm out of options with git pull(i can't do ssh git pull because i don't have access to the company git private server)

Comment: add `expect -timeout 60 eof` after sending the password. change the timeout value as needed.

Comment: Just curious here, why not use SSH keys and not have to deal with this?

Comment: @fredrik i mentioned in the question, i cannot setup ssh key authentication because i don't have access to the git server(can't edit authorized_keys file)

Comment: @sexpect-ExpectforShells thank you! that worked now, i wonder why i need expect eof at the end? if you can post it in the answer i will accept it

Comment: That seems like a strange setup. Is this some form of corporate setup? If so you should highlight this as an issue. In either case, I would look into using a credential helper instead of trying something like this. https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Credential-Storage

Comment: @fredrik yes it's a corporate setup for private git, normal dev like me who works as dev op cannot get access to the private git server for any setup. I tried git credential storage but it only works for https url, it doesn't work with ssh url sadly

Comment: Do this as workaround then - but raise this with managers. Ideally you should have some "real" git server (such as gerrit, gitlab or gitolite with an admin UI) with clear responsible persons highlighted.

Comment: @LinhNguyen -- it's like you close the terminal (e.g. in PuTTY) immediately after you input the password. that will kill the running git/ssh.

Comment: you can try my [sexpect](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect/). its default behaviors are more reasonable.

Comment: Read The Fine Manual: https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials works with `SSH_ASKPASS` as well

Comment: i love how they close the question while the one they linked only works for HTTPS urls, meanwhile i'm using ssh url